# how to make a json powered database

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, database, fs

Basically I've been having this idea where I'd create a Database, Lately I was learning about JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) and it seems to be one of the technologies I'd want to implement. I tried searching for this but I can't specifically find what I am actually looking for. This is how I would read the JSON data:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var JSONData;

var RAWJSONData = fs.readFileSync("pathtojson", "utf-8");
JSONData = JSON.parse(RAWJSONData, 0, null);
```

Am looking forward unto getting help and references on how I can create a Secure JSON Database and retrieve the JSON Data in a more Secure way in which no one else can access it except me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: json powered database . I think you can use mongodb ..

Comment: RethinkDB, MongoDB, CouchDB... Googling for JSON Database gives you plenty of places to get started.

Comment: Well my idea is to actually make a library like MongoDB and add more features

Comment: This question is way too broad. You want to make a library to store data? You'll have to store it somewhere... the library will be the facilitator to communicate with it, nothing else. There are a plenty of decent options available already but nobody is discouraging you from making one of your own but that is not a question you would ask on SO.